# Plesk Panel Dedicated SSL Login Issues

Tags: ssl-certificate, plesk, parallels, dedicated-server

Not entirely sure what I did to cause this but when I try to login to my dedicated server plesk panel it partially loads before throwing out an 501 error and says it can't connect to [https://server**-*-*-***.live-servers.net:11444/relay]. Now the only way I can login is by going to that address then proceed (chrome says it's insecure). Once I do that I just refresh the other page and the login shows up. I think I have to change some settings manually but I'm just not sure what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:11444 is for Plesk single sign on tool. For some reason it failed on your machine, but also it is quite likely you don't really need it. If you have ssh to your server, try this
`/usr/local/psa/bin/sso --disable` (for CentOS/RHEL)
or 
`/opt/psa/bin/sso --disable` (for Debian/Ubuntu)

Comment: Yea, I figured that out after about 2 hours of sifting through my configs.